# 8 files as input combination in shell script at Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below bash script that I need to take two at a time.Total have 8 files in folder.
And name of files is discontinuous like:

```
file5.txt   file7.txt  file11.txt  file13.txt  file14.txt  file21.txt   file22.txt   file23.txt
```

My script like:

```
caulatepet.py \
  --i file5.txt, file7.txt \
  --menscor men-code.list \
  --stat sex-rd.ratio \
  --out ./result/file5_file7.txt
```

I need to take two file as input at a time `(as --i input)`, like permutations and combinations.For example like below:

```
file5.txt file7.txt
file5.txt file11.txt
file5.txt file13.txt
file5.txt file14.txt
file5.txt file21.txt
file5.txt file22.txt
file5.txt file23.txt

file7.txt file11.txt
file7.txt file13.txt
file7.txt file14.txt
file7.txt file21.txt
file7.txt file22.txt
file7.txt file23.txt
...etc.
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: That seems like a silly thing to be doing **around** a Python program in shell script; write it in Python and build it into the program.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `for f1 in *; do for f2 in *; do if [ "${f1}" = "${f2}" ]; then continue; fi; caulatepet.py --i "${f1}" "${f2}" ... --out "./result/${f1}_{f2}.txt"; done; done` - However, this will run every pair of file twice - f1_f2 and f2_f1.

Comment: The argument of `--i` should most likely be escaped: `--i 'file5.txt, file7.txt'`. Otherwise, a traditional parser would take only `file5.txt,` as an argument for the `--i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to compare the files in pairs, but not comparing files to themselves (i.e. don't compare file5.txt to file5.txt) and only compare each pair once (i.e. after comparing file5.txt to file7.txt, it's not necessary to compare file7.txt to file5.txt). You should be able to do it by storing the filenames in an array, then making a double loop over the array:

```
files=(file5.txt file7.txt file11.txt file13.txt file14.txt file21.txt file22.txt file23.txt)

# for i as each index in the array...
for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do

    # for j as each index HIGHER THAN i in the array...
    for ((j=i+1; j<${#files[@]}; j++)); do

        caulatepet.py \
          --i "${files[i]}", "${files[j]}" \
          --menscor men-code.list \
          --stat sex-rd.ratio \
          --out "./result/${files[i]%.txt}_${files[j]}"

    done
done
```

BTW, the syntax of that `-i` option looks weird; is there really supposed to be a space after the `,`?

Answer (score 2):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org.txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr calcpairs.tl
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file7.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file7.txt
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file11.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file11.txt
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file13.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file13.txt
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file14.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file14.txt
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file21.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file21.txt
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file22.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file22.txt
caulatepet.py --i file5.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file5_file23.txt
caulatepet.py --i file7.txt, file11.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file7_file11.txt
caulatepet.py --i file7.txt, file13.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file7_file13.txt
caulatepet.py --i file7.txt, file14.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file7_file14.txt
caulatepet.py --i file7.txt, file21.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file7_file21.txt
caulatepet.py --i file7.txt, file22.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file7_file22.txt
caulatepet.py --i file7.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file7_file23.txt
caulatepet.py --i file11.txt, file13.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file11_file13.txt
caulatepet.py --i file11.txt, file14.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file11_file14.txt
caulatepet.py --i file11.txt, file21.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file11_file21.txt
caulatepet.py --i file11.txt, file22.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file11_file22.txt
caulatepet.py --i file11.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file11_file23.txt
caulatepet.py --i file13.txt, file14.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file13_file14.txt
caulatepet.py --i file13.txt, file21.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file13_file21.txt
caulatepet.py --i file13.txt, file22.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file13_file22.txt
caulatepet.py --i file13.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file13_file23.txt
caulatepet.py --i file14.txt, file21.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file14_file21.txt
caulatepet.py --i file14.txt, file22.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file14_file22.txt
caulatepet.py --i file14.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file14_file23.txt
caulatepet.py --i file21.txt, file22.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file21_file22.txt
caulatepet.py --i file21.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file21_file23.txt
caulatepet.py --i file22.txt, file23.txt --menscor men-code.list --stat sex-rd.ratio --out ./result/file22_file23.txt
```

Code:

```
(flow "file*.txt"
  glob
  (csort @1 : (do match `file@num.txt` @1
                (toint num)))
  (comb @1 2)
  (each-match ((@f1 @f2) @1)
    (sh `echo caulatepet.py \
        \ --i @f1, @f2 \
        \ --menscor men-code.list \
        \ --stat sex-rd.ratio \
        \ --out \
        \ ./result/@(trim-right ".txt" f1)_@f2`)))
```

We can remove `echo`  to run the program.

Annotated code:

```
;;; flow: start pipeline with "file*.txt" string
(flow "file*.txt"                       
  ;; glob: produce list of file names matching "file*.txt"
  glob

  ;; caching sort: sort list of names (argument @1) by number.
  ;; (do match ...) produces a function of one argument that
  ;; maps each item @1 to a sort key, which is the file number.
  ;; caching sort means the integer key is calculated only once
  ;; for each file and cached internally by csort.
  (csort @1 : (do match `file@num.txt` @1
                (toint num)))

  ;; calculate all two-element combinations of sorted list
  (comb @1 2)

  ;; iterate over combinations, destructuring them as f1 and f2
  (each-match ((@f1 @f2) @1)

    ;; invoke shell command with f1 and f2 inserted via quasistring
    (sh `echo caulatepet.py \
        \ --i @f1, @f2 \
        \ --menscor men-code.list \
        \ --stat sex-rd.ratio \
        \ --out \
        \ ./result/@(trim-right ".txt" f1)_@f2`)))
```

The `@1` syntax appears a few times. It indicates where in the implicit function should argument 1 be inserted.
By default, it's inserted on the right; e.g. with `glob`, we didn't need to write `(glob @1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Python, I suggest writing a helper script for generating the filename pair combinations. Luckily, Python has a built-in `combinations` function in the `itertools` package:

```py
import sys
from itertools import combinations

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filenames = sys.argv[1:]
    for pair in list(combinations(filenames, 2)):
        print("\x1F".join(pair))
```

Let's call it `pairs.py`. In the script above, the unit separator character `"\x1F"` is used as a delimiter because it is unprintable and thus unlikely to appear in the filenames. This is done for the sake of simplicity. In a production-level code, a better communication format (such as JSON) should be used.

Now we can generate the pairs and pipe them to your script as follows:

```bash
python pairs.py a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt | while IFS=$'\x1F' read -r f1 f2; do
    caulatepet.py \
      --i "$f1, $f2" \
      --menscor men-code.list \
      --stat sex-rd.ratio \
      --out "./result/${f1}_${f2}.txt"
done
```

Note that I've joined the two files into a single argument of the `--i` option because I think there is a little mistake in your question:

> --i file5.txt, file7.txt \

All popular shells (including bash), treat this sequence as three  separate arguments, and most of the traditional CLI argument parsers would interpret it as `--i` option with a `file5.txt,` value and the `file7.txt` would be interpreted as a separate argument, which doesn't make sense in the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

First add files to an array:

```
for f in *;{ arr+=("$f"); }
```

Than loop over it like this:

```
for ((i=0,j=1; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2,j+=2));{ echo ${arr[i]} ${arr[j]}; }
```

Result:

```
file1.txt file2.txt
file3.txt file4.txt
```